# Getting original time zone of DateTime value when parsing

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a set of `DateTime` text representations in ISO 8601 format, some of them have time zone specified. By default, `DateTime.Parse()` adjusts them to the local time zone (or to UTC with a special option), but in both cases the original time zone is missing. However, I need to detect which of `DateTime` strings were specified with the time zone and get its value for further processing.

Any ideas on how to do that?

UPD sample inputs:

2015-06-26T22:57:09Z
2015-06-26T22:57:09
2015-06-26T22:57:09+01:00

Comment: As per my knowledge, if the string representation has the timezone representation, then DateTime.Parse correctly sets the type of the datetime to Local Or Utc. Else it will set it to NotSpecified. Why not always pass around data in UTC. That will solve a lot of your conversion issues.

Comment: @Ganesh R., the input values are not mine.

Comment: Could you give an example of input? Also, would `DateTimeOffset`, ie https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx, solve your issue?

Comment: As above, you can't do this with `DateTime`.  If you can use it, `DateTimeOffset` is your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to clear a few things..

First of all both `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` are timezone awareness. A `DateTime` *might* know it's `UTC` or `Local`, but still, it can't know  what local *really* means. A `DateTimeOffset` is somewhat better, it keeps a UTC time with an [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). But still, these are not enough information to determine a timezone because different timezones can have same offsets.

`DateTime.Parse` *generally* returns a `DateTime` with `Kind` as `Unspecified`. It returns;

- `Local` when your string has time zone information.
- `UTC` when your string has time zone information and using `AdjustToUniversal` style **or** your string has Z or GMT designator and using `RoundtripKind` style.

That's why `DateTime.Parse("2015-06-26T22:57:09")` returns `Unspecified` but both `DateTime.Parse("2015-06-26T22:57:09Z")` and `DateTime.Parse("2015-06-26T22:57:09+01:00")` returns `Local` as a `Kind`. That's why no matter which you used, you will not get a *real* time zone information.

I would suggest you to used [`NodaTime`](http://nodatime.org/) instead. It has a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime.htm) structure as defined;

> A [`LocalDateTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_LocalDateTime.htm) **in a specific time zone** and with a particular
>   offset to distinguish between otherwise-ambiguous instants.

This structure is would be better for your case.